# I'm having trouble with my batch file recognizing pygame

Tags: python, batch-file, pygame

So, I wanted to make a batch file that runs all the python scripts. I did it correctly, except that it had a problem with pygame.

The batch file was to run all python scripts in a program folder. I started with a test and making the batch file run one script.

a. This is what I have done so far.

```
@echo off
python "C:\Users\Dylan Hawley\Documents\Python Files\TEST_GAMES\test\pygamebase.py" %*
pause
```

b. I also looked on this website and this is what the code is when I use the solution

```
@echo off
python -x %0 %* &goto :eof
python "C:\Users\Dylan Hawley\Documents\Python Files\TEST_GAMES\test\pygamebase.py" %*
pause
```

a. I expected for the bat file to run the script, but instead, I get an ImportError, more specifically,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File"C:\Users\Dylan Hawley\Documents\Python Files\TEST_GAMES\test\pygamebase.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pygame, math, sys
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

b. For this one, I expected for the solution to fix the error, but instead, when I open the batch file, it closes the command prompt and doesn't open the python file.

Answer (score 1):

You did't install `pygame` module correctly. May refer to the install instructions [here](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted):

Windows installation
Make sure you install python3.6 with the "Add python 3.6 to PATH" option selected. This means that python, and pip will work for you from the command line.
There is documentation with python for the "windows installation steps"

```
py -m pip install -U pygame --user
py -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

If you get:

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied'

before starting the cmd right click on it and "Run as administrator".

Comment: What if it tells me that the requirement is already up to date?

Comment: Update : reinstalled it multiple times, still get the error.